# parse error in simplepush php script of Ray Wenderlich IOS Notification Tutorial

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I'm following Ray Wenderlich's IOS Notification tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Its all gone well and the original tests which establish that I can connect to APNS and that my certificates are recognized all went well. I have an error though when trying to run the php script he supplies, though I have added the details requested and the ck.pem to the folder.
The full error is:
Parse error: parse error in /Users/carsoncarbery/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 10

And here is the code in my PHP script:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '521fbe4fbee30cb68ec7303a12a9d1ea56d89e6c18557479311f9417a2208415';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat!’;

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push woo hoo :-)’;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I should add that I'm new to this (hence trying to learn from the tutorials) and dont understand PHP yet, I've checked for solutions for this online but haven't found any references that can help.
Many thanks for any assistance

Comment: make sure ck.pem,entrust and simple push is in same folder.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I went back and recreated the ck.pem to makesure and then made sure again that it is in the same folder, but still get the error. One thing though what is the "entrust" I don't have a file of that name in my folder nore is it mentioned in the Tutorial??

Comment: you have not closed php tag in the last ?> in your php script

Comment: could you tell me how to do that please? I dont know PHP :-/ the tutorial is for IOS Xcode but needed a little PHP to make it work

Comment: as you have <?php in the starting of script same you should have ?> in the last.php script should be written in <?php   write script here   ?>

Comment: put ?> in the last after fclose line.

Comment: I added that at the end, but unfortunately still not working. What is the entrust you mentioned earlier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93668/discussion-between-johny-kumar-and-kitcc).

Comment: Bit embarrassing but I can't see the chat button, how do I start a chat in here?

Comment: click on automatically move this discussion to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at a little more I saw that 'pushchat!’, didn't have the correct closing comment '. As this was copied from a lesson, I'm not sure how it got in there. Any way thanks for the comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you mentioned above. I fixed it by doing the following steps,

1. download and unzip SimplePush.zip
2. Delete ck.pem from SimplePush folder
3. Copy and paste your ck.pem in SimplePush folder
4. Edit device token and passphrase in simplepush.php
5. Follow further steps from tutorial

Comment: if this is not working then please let me know the line number on which you are getting the error (I was getting parse error on line 7)